# I just want to know why eAccelerator won't work if SuPHP is enabled?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, web-server

I just want to know why people say eAccelerator won't work if SuPHP is enabled, because in my server I was running e-accelerator and now i have enabled suphp and it seems to be working fine so far at least ...

Questions are

1. is this a good idea to run both ?
2. if i am to disable the e-accelerator how do i do that ?
3. is there any alternative to do acceleration other than the e-accelerator when using suphp ?
4. What the tips for making the webserver fast with php ?
5. Any idea of the performance and recommendation of the XCache opcode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SuPHP requires a script to run as a specific user, given this I am not sure if using SuPHP in your environment is a requirement or not.

1. It is not a good idea because they do not work well together.
2. Disable eaccelerator in your `php.ini` file
3. There are no accelerators that work well with SuPHP.  I believe this has to do with how suPHP works, and because it starts and stops PHP as it needs.  All the accelerators require **persistent** PHP.
4. If you are able to not use SuPHP, then I would highly consider using APC - see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/420834/apc-xcache-or-eaccelerator-what-should-i-use-for-wordpress/420866#420866)
5. XCache does not work with SuPHP either to my knowledge

Look into FastCGI as it allows for caching to be setup and has lower overhead than SuPHP